# Условный оператор if в latex

Tags: if, latex

Нужно построить график (векторную диаграмму диода) причем если угол(\Fi) будет больше чем 90, то все вектора будут равны 0. Не понимаю как правильно использовать if в latex.

\usepackage{ifthen} подключил, пробовал разные вариации, но все время выдает ошибку.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Вот пример одной из моих попыток

```
$$
\frac{\partial \vec{I}} {\partial t}
$$

\begin{circuitikz}
\newcommand{\DV}{5}
\newcommand{\DI}{4}
\newcommand{\Fi}{80}
\newcommand{\Fii}{\Fi+7}
       \ifthenelse{\Fi < 90}
           {{\draw[->,blue] (0,0) -- ( {\DV*cos(\Fi)}, {\DV*sin(\Fi)}) node[right] {$\vec{V}$};
           \draw[->,red](0,0) --  ( {\DI*cos(\Fi -10)}, {\DI*sin(\Fi-10)}) node (A) {}node[below right] 
           {$\vec{I}(t)$};
          \draw[->,red](0,0) --  ( {\DI*cos(\Fii -10)}, {\DI*sin(\Fii-10)}) node (B) {}node[right] 
          {$\vec{I}(t+ {\small\Delta}t)$};
          \draw[->] (A.center) -- (B.center);
        \draw[->,ultra thin]    (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[below] {x}}

        {\draw[->,ultra thin]    (-6,0) -- (6,0)}
        
        
\end{circuitikz}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не претендую на абсолютную точность, но... В LaTeX можно целочисленные переменные делать через счетчики, а не через макросы (над счетчиками можно выполнять простейшие вычисления). Для обращения к значению счетчика можно использовать либо его имя с приставкой `\the` (например, для счетчика страниц `page` получить значение можно командой `\thepage`), либо используя специальную команду `\value{}` (например, `\value{page}`).

Можно отдельно протестировать работу условного оператора со счетчиками, а потом уже использовать соответствующие команды для рисования.

Короткий тестовый пример для условного оператора (кодировку и язык, конечно же, нужно указать свои)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{Fi}
\setcounter{Fi}{80}


\begin{document}         
    \ifthenelse{\theFi < 90}
    {true}
    {false}
\end{document}
```

должен вывести либо `true`, либо `false` в зависимости от значения счетчика и числа в условии. И в данном примере я обращаюсь к значению счетчика через команду `\theFi`
(спойлер: при указанных значениях далжно быть выведено `true`).

Далее, можно переходить к программе с рисунком. Нужно задать все переменные как счетчики, задать им нужные значения и после этого можно к ним обращаться (в следующем примере, для разнообразия, применим команду `\value{}`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\newcounter{DV}
\newcounter{DI}
\newcounter{Fii}
\newcounter{Fi}

\setcounter{DV}{5}
\setcounter{DI}{4}
\setcounter{Fi}{80}
\setcounter{Fii}{\value{Fi}} %здесь TeX не дает прямо сложить с числом, поэтому добавляем 7 следующей строкой
\addtocounter{Fii}{7}

\begin{document}

    $$
    \frac{\partial \vec{I}} {\partial t}
    $$
    
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \ifthenelse{\value{Fi} < 90}
            {
                \draw[->,blue] (0,0) -- ( {\value{DV}*cos(\value{Fi})}, {\value{DV}*sin(\value{Fi})}) node[right] {$\vec{V}$};
                \draw[->,red](0,0) --  ( {\value{DI}*cos(\value{Fi} -10)}, {\value{DI}*sin(\value{Fi}-10)}) node (A) {}node[below right] {$\vec{I}(t)$};
                \draw[->,red](0,0) --  ( {\value{DI}*cos(\value{Fii} -10)}, {\value{DI}*sin(\value{Fii}-10)}) node (B) {}node[right]  {$\vec{I}(t+ {\small\Delta}t)$};
                \draw[->] (A.center) -- (B.center);
                \draw[->,ultra thin]    (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[below] {x};
            }
            {
                \draw[->,ultra thin]    (-6,0) -- (6,0)
            }                
    \end{circuitikz}
    
\end{document}
```

В итоге, получился странный рисунок, но думаю, что это именно то, что просили нарисовать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]